# How do I download discord.py on Raspbian?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a small discord bot with python, and I ran the pip command to download it, but it gave me this error:

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip-install/KE0yK1/discord/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
with open(path.join(this-directory, README.md), encoding='utf-8') as f:
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: That looks like you have code that expects Python 3 running using Python 2. How did you install the `pip` command?

Comment: use python3....: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip && python -m pip install discord`

Comment: Raspbian came preloaded with Python I believe, or at least the Thonny IDE. I think it just came with that

Comment: Raspbian does come preloaded with Python but at least Raspbian-lite does not have `pip` unless you install it. Maybe the full version does.

Comment: @RocStar Raspbian comes by default with python2 but you can install python3, try what I pointed out in my previous comment

Comment: Eyllanesc I tried running that command but it gave me the same error

Comment: if you have installed `python3` then you should use `pip3` or `python3 -m pip install ...` to install modules for `python3`. `pip` and `python` should still use `python2`. Check `python -V` and `pip -V`